# Bootstrap Implementation with Joomla

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla2.5

Is it possible to implement 100% of bootstrap in joomla without any custom css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's this great article about building a theme with Twitter Bootstrap.

http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-aug-2012/item/818-using-the-twitter-bootstrap-framework-to-build-a-responsive-joomla-template-from-scratch

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a new site. Take a look at Joomla 3.0 as it comes with Bootstrap by default (as well as jQuery).

Comment: J3.0 implements Bootstrap on the back end only.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can implement Bootstrap without adding any custom CSS< but why would you do that? Bootstrap is not a full blown template or layout. It is a framework used to facilitate creating a template or layout. Even on the Bootstrap examples page they specify that these should be a starting point, not the end product.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples

If you want to create a custom template, it would make sense to start with the started Bootstrap template, adapt it for Joomla, then add the custom CSS and images to make it look good.

It would be a good idea to also look at Joostrap (http://www.joostrap.com/). They have a very nice basic template that we base all of our custom work on.

Answer (score 0):

I have built some templates for Joomla 3.0, Bootstrap in Joomla 3.0 doesn't support all Glyphicons that Twitter Bootstrap supports, so if you want to use the missing icons you will need to add your custom CSS.

If you build a responsive template for Joomla 2.5, there will be a lot of works to do, not only for CSS, default extensions in Joomla 2.5 are not responsive so you may need to override their default layouts.